# Vector Spaces and Linear Transformations ($T^2 = 0 \iff R(T) \subseteq N(T)$).

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, linear-transformations

Let $V$ be a vector space over a field $F$. Let $T: V\to W$ be a linear transformation.

a. Prove that $T^2=0$ if and only if $R(T)$ is contained in $N(T)$. (Here we denote $T^2$ as the linear transformation such that $T^2(v)=T(T(v))$ for all $v$ in $V$)

b. Assume that $V$ is finite-dimensional and $T^2=0$. Prove that $\operatorname{nullity}(T)$ is greater than or equal to $\dim(V)/2$.

Comment: Welcome to math.se! For clarification, when you write $R(T)$, do you mean the image of $T$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Part (a):

- $(\Longrightarrow)$: Choose any $\vec y \in R(T)$ so that there is some $\vec x \in V$ such that $T(\vec x) = \vec y$. Then since $T^2 = 0$, it follows that:
  $$
  T(\vec y) = T(T(\vec x)) = T^2(\vec x) = \vec 0
  $$
  Hence, $\vec y \in N(T)$, as desired.
- $(\Longleftarrow)$: Choose any $\vec x \in V$. Then $T(\vec x) \in R(T) \subseteq N(T)$. Hence, it follows that $T^2(\vec x) = T(T(\vec x)) = \vec 0$, as desired.

Part (b):

Since $T^2 = 0$, we know by part (a) that $R(T) \subseteq N(T)$ so that $\dim(R(T)) \leq \dim(N(T))$. But then by the Rank-Nullity Theorem, it follows that:
$$
\dim V = \dim(R(T)) + \dim(N(T)) \leq \dim(N(T)) + \dim(N(T)) = 2\dim(N(T))
$$
Hence, we conclude that $\text{nullity}(T) = \dim(N(T)) \geq \frac{1}{2}\dim(V)$, as desired. $~~\blacksquare$

Answer (score 0):

For (a) see the comment to your question.

For (b) let $r$ be the rank of $T$, and $k$ be the nullity of $T$, with $n$ the dimension of $V$. Since $r+k=n$ by the rank-nullity theorem, and since $r\le k$, since $R(T)\subset N(T)$ by (a), we have $2r \le r+k \le n$, or $r\le n/2$ as desired.